# Force Azure DevOps to allow only Fast Forward Merge

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops, pull-request

I would like to use Azure DevOps Pull Request with a strict behavior.

Merges are only done on the Development branch and the server Enforce only Fast Forward merges to master.

I did not found a way to force this behavior on Azure DevOps.
Is there a way to set this option?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the docs: Looks like you can do it in a simple way, since FF is not supported as a selected merge stategy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

---

#### Enforce a merge strategy

Maintain a consistent branch history by enforcing a merge strategy when a pull request finishes. 
Select Enforce a merge strategy and pick an option to require that pull requests merge using that strategy.

[image]
Set merge requirements

- **No fast-forward merge** - This option merges the commit history of the source branch when the pull request closes and creates a merge commit in the target branch.
- **Squash merge** - Complete all pull requests with a squash merge, creating a single commit in the target branch with the changes from the source branch. Learn more about squash merging and how it affects your branch history.

---

#### Using git hook to enforce this option

You can do it by setting up git hook which will verify that the commit you are pushing is "on top" of the required commit

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# for details see here, 
# http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

refname=$1
oldrev=$2
newrev=$3


# enforces fast-forward only pushes
check_fast_forward ()
{
  all_refs=`git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev} | wc  -l`
  single_parent_refs=`git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev} --max-parents=1 | wc  -l `
  if [ $all_refs -eq $single_parent_refs ]; then
    echo "This is the section for fast-forward commits ..."
    exit 0
  fi
}

check_fast_forward
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and great answar. From what I read the Azure DevOps does not support git hooks. Am I missing something? Is there a way to use your method on Azure DevOps? Thank you

Comment: The docs are actually not up to date. Since sprint 150 update rebase or fast forward has been available as enforceable merge strategies.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/pull-requests-with-rebase/

Comment: Non fast forward merges will ensure the history is not lost, creating a new commit on each merge (non linear). enforcing fast forward only merges (linear) is still not available as an option in AZ Devops as far as I can see.  the option for the rebase strategy creates a linear history, but it doesn't enforce it (it doesn't use a fast forward strategy)

Answer (score 0):

> Force Azure DevOps to allow only Fast Forward Merge

Just like Erik P comment, this feature has been released with Sprint 150:

[New merge types for completing pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-150-update#new-merge-types-for-completing-pull-requests):

> You now have more options when merging the changes from a pull request
>   to the target branch. We have added support for two of our most
>   requested features on the Developer Community: [Fast-Forward merging](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365639/enable-fastforward-merge-from-pullrequest.html)
>   and [Semi-Linear merging](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365761/add-rebase-and-merge-to-pull-requests.html) (also called “Rebase and Merge”).

[image]

But some folks saying this feature is not complete, if you have the same question, you could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

[Fast forward merge in pull requests](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/767638/pull-request-merge-option-two-way-merge-but-fast-f.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see why some are saying the feature is not complete. Imagine you have a branch with *new merge commits* on it, that you wish to PR into another branch. You might prefer either "ff if possible otherwise regular merge", or "only allow ff merge". In the latter case the user would probably elect to merge the target branch into the source branch first, and then complete the PR. In no case would the user wish to rebase the source branch (and pop the merge commits) before performing a ff merge.

Comment: Even though "rebase and ff" only rebases if needed, it's still risky if the source branch has merge commits. The user might think it's safe to choose that option because the source branch is currently up to date, but if someone else sneaks a PR into the target first, then the the source branch gets rebased and the merge commits get dropped (potentially causing conflicts too).